# How to give a div tag focus when its contents are clicked using JQuery or CSS

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

Is there a way to give a div tag focus when you click on its contents? Using CSS or JQuery?

Comment: You'll probably get (better) answers to this at http://doctype.com/

Comment: I don't think a DIV *can* have focus at all. Focus is reserved to actual input elements.  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Pekka I want the border and background highlighted when the div tags contents are clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 draft extends the [tabindex attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex) so that setting it to 0 or a negative number will make an element focus-able if it isn't usually so.

The usual provisos about new features in drafts having limited browser support and limited support by assistive technologies (such as screen readers) apply.

In general, if you need to be able to give the focus to a control, it is better to pick an element that is designed to accept the focus in the first place.